# How to remove rings from convolve healpix map?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing, healpy

I'm applying convolution techniques to convolve 2 datasets, a healpix map with nside = 256 and a primary beam of shape (256, 256) in order to measure the total intensity from the convolved healpix map. My problem is that after convolving my map with the primary beam i get rings in my convolved map. I've tried normalizing it with either lanczos or Gaussian kernel to take care of the rings but all these approaches have failed.

In my code below, i used the query function in scipy to search for the nearest pixels in my healpix map within a given radius and take the sum of the product of the corresponding pixels in the primary beam using map coordinate. The final image i get has rings in it. Please can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
def query_npix(nside, npix, radius):
    print 'searching for nearest pixels:......'
    t1, t2 = hp.pix2ang(nside, np.arange(npix)) 
    tree = spatial.cKDTree(zip(t1, t2))

    dist, ipix_indx = tree.query(zip(t1, t2), k = 150, distance_upper_bound = radius)
    r1, r2 = hp.pix2ang(nside, ipix_indx)
    ra = r1.T - t1
    dec = r2.T - t2
    print 'Done searching'
    return np.array(dist), np.array(ipix_indx), np.array(ra.T), np.array(dec.T)

def fullSky_convolve(healpix_map, primary_beam_fits, ipix_indx, dist, radius, r1, r2):

    measured_map = []

    hdulist = openFitsFile(primary_beam_fits)
    beam_data = hdulist[0].data
    header = hdulist[0].header  
    nside = hp.get_nside(healpix_map[0, ...])
    npix = hp.get_map_size(healpix_map[0, ...])         # total number of pixels in the map must be  12 * nside^2 

    crpix1, crval1, cdelt1 = [ header.get(x) for x in "CRPIX1", "CRVAL1", "CDELT1" ]
    crpix2, crval2, cdelt2 = [ header.get(x) for x in "CRPIX2", "CRVAL2", "CDELT2" ]

    # beam centres in pixel coordinates
    xc = crpix1-1 + (np.rad2deg(r1.ravel()) - crval1)/(256*cdelt1)
    yc = crpix2-1 + (np.rad2deg(r2.ravel()) - crval2)/(256*cdelt2)
    #xc =  (np.rad2deg(r1.ravel()) )/cdelt1

    for j in xrange(4):
        print 'started Stokes: %d' %j

        for iter in xrange(0 + j, 16, 4):
            outpt = np.zeros(shape = npix, dtype=np.float64)
            #by = outpt.copy()
            # mask beam
            bm_data = beam_data[iter]
            #masked_beam= beam_data[iter]
            shape = bm_data.shape
            rad = np.linspace(-shape[0]/2,shape[-1]/2,shape[0])
            rad2d =  np.sqrt(rad[np.newaxis,:]**2+rad[:,np.newaxis]**2)
            mask = rad2d <= radius/abs(cdelt2)
            masked_beam = bm_data*mask

            s1 = ndimage.map_coordinates(masked_beam, [xc, yc], mode = 'constant')
            bm_map = s1.reshape(dist.shape[0], dist.shape[-1])

        for itr in xrange(npix):
            g_xy = (1.0/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*np.std(dist[itr])))*np.exp(-(dist[itr])**2/(2*np.var(dist[itr])))
            #weighted_healpix_map = np.convolve(healpix_map[j, ...][ipix_indx[itr]],  g_xy/g_xy.sum(), mode='same')
            weighted_healpix_map = ndimage.filters.convolve(healpix_map[j, ...][ipix_indx[itr]],  g_xy/g_xy.sum(), mode='reflect')
            #outpt[itr] = np.sum(weighted_healpix_map*(bm_map[itr]/bm_map[itr].sum()))
            outpt[itr] = np.sum(weighted_healpix_map*(bm_map[itr]))
            #print 'itr', itr           
            alpha = file('pap%d.save'%iter, 'wb')
            #h_map = ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(outpt, sigma = 3.)
            cPickle.dump(outpt, alpha, protocol = cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            alpha.close()
            print 'Just dumped stripp%d.save:-------'%iter
    print 'Loading dumped files:-------'
    loaded_objects = []
    for itr4 in xrange(16):
        alpha = file('stripp%d.save'%itr4, 'rb')
        loaded_objects.append(cPickle.load(alpha))
        alpha.close()
        measured_map.append(copy.deepcopy(loaded_objects))
    return measured_map
```

Comment: have you tried in spherical harmonics space? is that an option?

Comment: please, can you elaborate further on the spherical harmonics space?

Comment: @TAN, I think people could be a lot more help if you reduced your code a bit and tried to explain a little more about what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that HEALPix maps can be in either "Ring" or "Nested" format. It sounds like you may need to add the keyword `nest=True` to your healpy functions like `hp.pix2ang`. If your input maps are in *nested* format, this keyword is needed.

For example:
    I recently tried using the `healpy.smoothing()` function, and found my resulting image to have rings (perhaps like you described), upon viewing the output map with `healpix.mollview()`. The rings disappeared and the image was presented as I expected, after running `mollview` with the `nested=True` keyword. Check what ordering schemes your input files use

> Reference:
>       http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-and-manipulating-maps
>
> Healpix supports two different ordering schemes, RING or NESTED. By
>   default, healpy maps are in RING ordering. In order to work with
>   NESTED ordering, all map related functions support the nest keyword,
>   for example: hp.mollview(m, nest=True, title="Mollview image NESTED")